# Unable to show two Decimals properly in Round(value,2) in h2 database

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

Hello guys i have a small problem but this is creating big irritating to view the query.

i have a table which have values to for calculations, i want to show all my calculation in `2 decimals` values after `sum` of the values

example calculation
some `table xyz`

```
product | quantity   |   answer
 10     |   20       |    30.00
 23.53  |   11.23    |   264.2419
```

here is the query

```
query : select round(product*quantity,2) from xyz

Output
 30.0
264.24
```

i am getting exact output but i am unable to get two decimals for `30.0`  as `30.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, this will fulfil your need.

```
select CAST(round(product*quantity,2) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
from xyz
```